# How to calculate $x_t$ from $ARIMA(1,2,0)$ (second difference $AR(1)$ process)?

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

It sounds so simple but I'v struggled with this problem for a quite long time now.

I have come to this:
$$X_t = \phi(x_{t-1} - 2x_{t-2} + x_{t-3}) + 2x_{t-1} - x_{t-2} + \epsilon_t$$

it just doesn't give the right values..

Comment: What's your data ? What did you try to do ?

Comment: My data is just some autogenerated process. This is a task from time series analysis course. I found right model for the process which is two times differenced AR on first lag. I just wanted to write the estimate of x_{t}. I came to equation \Delta^2 x_{t} = \phi \Delta^2 x_{t-1} + \epsilon_{t} and simplified it to the equation on my post. So when I found estimate for phi with spss and inserted values to equation it just gives wrong values :(

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with how SPSS computes your model ?

Comment: Ljung-Box value is >0.218 and AR lag 1 is significant (p<0.001). Also fit plot seems to follow original process.. Don't know. Now I feel that maybe I've just totally misunderstanded everything :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are asking about what kind of process is obtained from differencing twice a stationary AR(1).
Let $L$ be the [lag operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lag_operator) $\left( Lx_t = x_{t - 1} \right)$. This simplifies the algebra.

- $y_t = \left( 1 - L \right)^2 x_t$ ($y_t$ is obtained by differencing
  $x_t$ twice)
- $x_t \left( 1 - \phi L \right) = \varepsilon_t$ ($x_t$ is a first
  order stationary AR(1) assuming $|\phi|<1$)
- $x_t = \left( 1 - \phi L \right)^{- 1} \varepsilon_t$ (here $\left( 1
    - \phi L \right)^{- 1} = \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \phi^i L^i$)
- Combining both we get
  \begin{eqnarray*}
      y_t & = & \left( 1 - L \right)^2 x_t\\
      & = & \left( 1 - L \right)^2 \left( 1 - \phi L \right)^{- 1}
      \varepsilon_t
    \end{eqnarray*}
  Finally
  $$ y_t \left( 1 - \phi L \right) = \left( 1 - L \right)^2 \varepsilon_t $$
  this means
  $$ y_t = \phi y_{t - 1} + \varepsilon_t - 2 \varepsilon_{t - 1} +
       \varepsilon_{t - 2} $$
  This means $y_t$ is ARIMA(1,0,2), stationary but not invertible process.